# MongoDB aggregation grouping documents without accumaltion

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Using MongoDB's aggregate pipeline, I want to be able to group documents by a value without any accumulation.

For example, I want to group this collection by `key`:

```
[
   {
      "_id":"323232",
      "name":"Something",
      "key":"A",
      "price":"100"
   },
   {
      "_id":"157236",
      "name":"Another thing",
      "key":"B",
      "price":75
   },
   {
      "_id":"555232",
      "name":"Something or another",
      "key":"B",
      "price":78
   }
]
```

Desired result:

```
[
   {
       "_id":"A",
       "results": [
           {
              "_id":"323232",
              "name":"Something",
              "key":"A",
              "price":"100"
           }
       ]
   },
   {
       "_id":"A",
       "results": [
           {
              "_id":"157236",
              "name":"Another thing",
              "key":"B",
              "price":75
           },
           {
              "_id":"555232",
              "name":"Something or another",
              "key":"B",
              "price":78
           }
       ]
   }
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this?

```
db.test.aggregate([
    {
        $sort : {"price" : 1}
    },
    {
        $group : {
            _id : '$key',
            results : {
                $push : {
                    "_id":"$_id",
                    "name":"$name",
                    "key":"$key",
                    "price":"$price"
                }
            }
        }
    }
]).pretty()
```

Comment: Thanks.  How would I then order the documents in `results` by `price`?

Comment: You can try first sorting all the documents by price using `$sort` and then use `$group`. See the edit.

Answer (score 2):

check this

```
db.coll.aggregate([
                    { "$group" : {
                              '_id' :'$key',
                              result: {$push:'$$ROOT'}
                            }
                    }
                 ]);
```

Comment: Thanks.  How would I then order the documents in `results` by `price`?